# Using AngularJS ajax to post data to API in sails.js backend

Tags: ajax, angularjs, node.js, sails.js

I am new and a bit confused about using AngularJS to POST form data to the API of sails.js, but the form does not work, with this not-so-informative error:  **TypeError: string is not a function**

I was wondering what might be wrong. I'm suspecting the API I'm using is wrong in the `$http.post()`, but I'm not sure.

I have the following `Employee` model and `EmployeeController` method called `regEmployee()`:

**Employee Model:**

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    name:{
      type:"string",
      required:true,
      minLength: 2
    },
    empnum:{
      type:"string",
      required:true,
      unique: true
    },
    email:{
      type:"email",
      required:true,
      unique: true
    }
  }
};
```

**regEmployee() method:**

```
$scope.regEmployee = function() {
    $http.post("http://localhost:1337/employee/create", {name: $scope.employee.name,
        empnum: $scope.employee.number, email: $scope.employee.email}

    ).success($scope.message = "successful registration"
    ).error($scope.message = "failed registration");
}
```

**The form in html:**

```
<form name="newEmp" ng-submit="regEmployee()" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group-lg">
      <label for="name">Employee Name: </label>
      <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Employee Name" ng-model="employee.name" name="name" ng-required="true">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group-lg">
      <label for="number">Employee Number: </label>
      <input type="number" id="number" placeholder="Employee Number" ng-model="employee.number" name="number" ng-required="true">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group-lg">
      <label for="email">Employee Email: </label>
      <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Employee Email" ng-model="employee.email" name="email" ng-required="true">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>


  </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are passing strings to your .success and .error functions instead of call back functions. 
you need something like

```js
$scope.regEmployee = function() {
    $http.post("http://localhost:1337/employee/create", {name: $scope.employee.name,
        empnum: $scope.employee.number, email: $scope.employee.email}

    ).success(function() {$scope.message = "successful registration";})
    ).error(function() {$scope.message = "failed registration"});
}
```